# How to loop through JSON array and get specific values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

How can I loop through the array below and get the values of "car1"? The code below returns *undefined*

```
<script>
var myObj = {
  "cars": {
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  },
  "cars2": {
    "car1":"Ford2",
    "car2":"BMW2",
    "car3":"Fiat2"
  }
}

for (x in myObj) {
 alert(x.car1);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: Do `console.log( x )` inside the loop

Comment: `Object.values(myObj).forEach(i => console.log(i.car1))`

Comment: Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => alert(myObj[key].car1))

Comment: Always read the documentation of syntax you are not familiar with, do not assume. Read about `for...in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your loop:

```
for (x in myObj) {
 alert(x.car1);
}
```

x is the string value of key of your object. In order to get the  car1 property of your nested object you can  change your loop as:

```
for (x in myObj) {
 alert(myObj[x].car1);
}
```

It is also a good practice to use  [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) while using `for-in` loop it might also  iterate  over  properties which are in your object's prototype chain.

```
for (x in myObj) {
 if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
   alert(myObj[x].car1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For aggregating those values into an array, for example:

```js
    let aggregated = [];
    var myObj = {
      "cars": {
        "car1":"Ford",
        "car2":"BMW",
        "car3":"Fiat"
      },
      "cars2": {
        "car1":"Ford2",
        "car2":"BMW2",
        "car3":"Fiat2"
      }
    }

    Object.keys(myObj).forEach(e => {
      aggregated.push(myObj[e].car1)
    })
    
    console.log(aggregated)
```

Comment: So far this is the best answer as it's not stuck in ES5 land :),..  But you could make this even nicer with ->  `const aggregated = Object.values(myObj).map(i => i.car1)`

Comment: thank you. If I may ask as well, how can I add a if or statement to this to test if car1 = ford (and not ford2)?

Comment: @YWSW You would just use filter on this result.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any other object inside and you want to get access to their properties too, you can create nested loop, like this:

```js
var myObj = {
  "cars": {
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  },
  "cars2": {
    "car1":"Ford2",
    "car2":"BMW2",
    "car3":"Fiat2"
  }
}

// Iterate over the first level
for (x in myObj) {
  // Iterate over the second level
  for (y in myObj[x]) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[x][y] + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

This way you will be able to iterate through `myObj[cars]` and `myObj[cars2]` object properties too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `car1` property isn't at the level that you're trying to access it at. Loop through the object and check to see if car1 exists on the next level down. If it does, show the alert. Also note, you should have an `if` statement in your `for in` loop to make sure the property exists (or some other condition)

```js
var myObj = {
  "cars": {
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  },
  "cars2": {
    "car1":"Ford2",
    "car2":"BMW2",
    "car3":"Fiat2"
  }
}

for (var x in myObj) {
 if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
    var obj = myObj[x];
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('car1')) {
        alert(obj.car1);
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var myObj = {
        "cars": {
            "car1": "Ford",
            "car2": "BMW",
            "car3": "Fiat"
        },
        "cars2": {
            "car1": "Ford2",
            "car2": "BMW2",
            "car3": "Fiat2"
        }
    }

    var res = Object.values(myObj)
        .map(i => i.car1)
        .filter(name => (name !== 'Ford2'));

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the for loop to

```
for (x in myObj) alert(myObj[x].car1);
```

Try it out

Answer (score 0):

You have a small misgiving here. You're not looping over an Array, you are looping over the properties of an Object with a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

You should be careful with that. You probably want to make it 'safe'(won't traverse the prototype or non enumerable properties) by changing to a more updated methods of traversal. Namely safely getting the values of the object, not the keys and then looping over it with some of the newer looping functions.

We'll be using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get an array of the values since we don't need the keys, then [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out anything without a 'car1' property as reported by [`Object.prototype.hasownproperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), and finally mapping over it to transform it with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). As a way to keep the alerts in, we will then be alerting on each of them using [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)

```
Object
  .values(myObj) // since we don't care about the keys, only loop over the values
  .filter(obj => // filter out any values without a 'car1' property
    obj.hasOwnProperty('car1') 
  )
  .map(obj => obj.car1) // de-nest the car1 property
  .forEach(alert)
```

Now we have an array of the car1 properties of the values in the Object. The good news is this will work if given an Array of objects as well instead of a nested Object, but only because we don't care about the keys that hold the objects and only that an object actually has a 'car1' property

---

## Tricks used for brevity

### Arrow Functions

```
function (a,b){ return console.log(a,b) }
```

can be rewritten as

```
(a,b) => console.log(a,b)
```

### Direct function reference

```
[1,2,3].forEach(item => alert(item))
```

can be rewritten since in JavaScript functions are first order and can be passed as arguments to other functions

```
[1,2,3].forEach(alert)
```